# Looking for Firefox add-on to switch to the last but one accessed tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I like to use Ctrl-Tab hotkey to switch between the current tab and the last accessed one. But, this time and another I need to switch to the last but one in stead. Is there any hidden toggle or an extension (preferably, a lite one, rather than some super-universal extension consuming a lot of RAM with 95% of functions to be useless (for me)) that would allow a hotkey to be assigned to such an action?